# CMake subdirectories dependency

Tags: dependencies, cmake, subdirectory

I am very new to CMake. In fact, I am trying it through Kdevelop4 widh C++.

I have the habit of creating subdirs for every namespace I create, even if all the sources must be compiled and linked into a single executable. Well, when i create a directory under kdevelop, it updates CMakeLists.txt with a add_subdirectory command and creates a new CMakeLists.txt under it, but that alone does not add the sources under it to the compilation list.

I have the root CMakeLists.txt as follows:

```
project(gear2d)

add_executable(gear2d object.cc main.cc)

add_subdirectory(component)
```

Under component/ I have the sources I want to be compiled and linked to produce the gear2d executables. How can I accomplish that?

CMake FAQ have [this](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#How_can_I_add_a_dependency_to_a_source_file_which_is_generated_in_a_subdirectory.3F) entry but if thats the answer I'd rather stay with plain Makefiles.

Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Adding a subdirectory does not do much more than specify to CMake that it should enter the directory and look for another CMakeLists.txt there. You still need to create a library with the source files with [add_library](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command%3aadd_library) and link it to your executable with [target_link_libraries](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command%3atarget_link_libraries). Something like the following:

In the subdir CMakeLists.txt

```
set( component_SOURCES ... ) # Add the source-files for the component here
# Optionally you can use file glob (uncomment the next line)
# file( GLOB component_SOURCES *.cpp )below

add_library( component ${component_SOURCES} )
```

Top-dir CMakeLists.txt

```
project( gear2d )
add_subdirectory( component )
add_executable( gear2d object.cc main.cc )
target_link_libraries( gear2d component )
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks very much. I had other concept for what a library means, in fact what I was expecting just to add the sources in the subdir CMakeListrs.txt just like it was done in the root one, with add_executable. Thanks again.

Comment: This basically adds a new (library) target. Even though this target doesn't get linked itself, problems might arise later on when setting comiler flags or other stuff...

Better answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934295/add-source-in-a-subdirectory-to-a-cmake-project

Comment: @kralyk: I agree on the new library target. For convencience, I skimmed over "linked into a single executable" and simply wanted to hint on another method of distributing source files over directories and libraries.

Comment: You sir, put an end to banging my head against the wall. Thank you.

Comment: I would like to add the suggestion to rename the subdir 'component' in the example to 'componentdir'. Just to make clear that `target_link_libraries` expects the target name 'component' from *within* the subdir's CMakeLists.txt. Since this is at least the 3rd place in the web where I found examples with equal names for subdir and link-item, I got a little confused and had to try it out myself... (if perhaps the subdir name would also work for `target_link_libraries` - but it doesn't; by the way you also cannot use a ${...} alias defined in the subdir...)

Comment: Thanks for easy solution !!

Comment: Thanks @yau - your comment saved me! Was very confused for a bit