# Add Source in a subdirectory to a cmake project

Tags: cmake

I have project which has not been divided into libraries, but the source is organized in a directory tree.  I do not know how to tell cmake to go down a directory, then add the source in that directory to project defined in the parent directory.  I have attempted the following:

in project/source/CMakelists.txt:

```
set(SOURCE
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/unitTest/main.cpp
  )
add_subdirectory("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/folder1")
add_executable(UnitTestRNG ${SOURCE} ${HEADERS})
```

then in project/source/folder1/CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(SOURCE
   ${SOURCE}
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/file1.cpp
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/file2.cpp
)
set(HEADERS
   ${HEADERS}
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/file1.hpp
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/file2.hpp
)
```

using some message() statements, I have found that the the child folder will get the contents of the SOURCE variable, but it's new assignment to that variable will not persist on returning to the parent CMakeLists.txt

Looking for examples and at the cmake tutorial has led me to the conclusion that:
 - Source file structures are usually flat within a project
 - If code is divided into folders, it is usually is divided into corresponding libraries.

I wonder if there is some "best practice" from which I am deviating by attempting this structure.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Since CMake 3.1 there is a new way to add source from subdirectories: [`target_sources`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/command/target_sources.html)

Say you have `root_dir` and `root_dir/sub_dir` and source files in both. With `target_sources` you can do this:

In `root_dir/CMakeLists.txt` define the target

```
add_library(some_target main.cpp)
add_subdirectory(sub_dir)
```

In `root_dir/sub_dir/CMakeLists.txt` add sources:

```
target_sources(some_target PRIVATE more_cool_stuff.cpp)
```

`some_target` will now contain both source files.

It is also possible to use other commands in `root_dir/sub_dir/CMakeLists.txt` using `some_target`, for example `target_compile_definitions` which is quite convenient to add compilation definitions.

I learned about `target_sources` [here, check it out if you want more explanation and examples](https://crascit.com/2016/01/31/enhanced-source-file-handling-with-target_sources/)

Answer (score 39):

Like the second part of arrowdodger's answer says:
 in project/source/folder1/CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(SOURCE
   ${SOURCE}
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/file1.cpp
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/file2.cpp
   PARENT_SCOPE
)
set(HEADERS
   ${HEADERS}
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/file1.hpp
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/file2.hpp
   PARENT_SCOPE
)
```

Comment: Is this still the recommended way to achieve this in the latest version of cmake?

Comment: No. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54285898/3554391)

Answer (score 6):

Can't you just set all your sources in project/source/CMakelists.txt then?

Anyway, what you need is `PARENT_SCOPE` or `CACHE` option on [set command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command%3aset).

Comment: The first part of your answer is indeed what I've been doing in the interim.