# CMake -- Add all sources in subdirectory to cmake project

Tags: c++, cmake

As a follow up to this question:
[Add Source in a subdirectory to a cmake project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934295/add-source-in-a-subdirectory-to-a-cmake-project)

What is the best way (perhaps using the FILE directive?) to select *all* the .cpp and .h files in the subdirectory and add them to the SOURCE variable defined in the parent directory?

---

Example from answer to question above:

```
set(SOURCE
  ${SOURCE}
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/file1.cpp
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/file2.cpp
  PARENT_SCOPE
)

set(HEADERS
   ${HEADERS}
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/file1.hpp
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/file2.hpp
   PARENT_SCOPE
)
```

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
FILE(GLOB SUB_SOURCES *.cpp)
set(SOURCE
  ${SOURCE}
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${SUB_SOURCES}
  PARENT_SCOPE
)
```

What is the best way (using CMake) to compile all the sources in a directory and a subdirectory into a single output file (not multiple libraries?)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027247/best-way-to-specify-sourcefiles-in-cmake

Comment: You are missing GLOB in your `FILE(SUB_SOURCES *.cpp)`. Change it to `FILE(GLOB SUB_SOURCES *.cpp)`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the `aux_source_directory` command.

> aux_source_directory Find all source files in a directory.
>
> aux_source_directory( )
>
> Collects the names of all the source files in the specified directory
>   and stores the list in the  provided.  This command is
>   intended to be used by projects that use explicit template
>   instantiation.  Template instantiation files can be stored in a
>   "Templates" subdirectory and collected automatically using this
>   command to avoid manually listing all instantiations.
>
> It is tempting to use this command to avoid writing the list of source
>   files for a library or executable target.  While this seems to work,
>   there is no way for CMake to generate a build system that knows when a
>   new source file has been added.  Normally the generated build system
>   knows when it needs to rerun CMake because the CMakeLists.txt file is
>   modified to add a new source.  When the source is just added to the
>   directory without modifying this file, one would have to manually
>   rerun CMake to generate a build system incorporating the new file.

Your CMakeLists.txt within the subdirectory could look like this:

```
aux_source_directory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} SUB_SOURCES)

set(SOURCE
  ${SOURCE}
  ${SUB_SOURCES}
  PARENT_SCOPE
)
```

The recommended practice is however, as you see from the documentation, to list the files individually within CMakeLists.txt as changes to the CMakeLists.txt file triggers running cmake.

I hope this was helpful and to the point.