# Why am I getting Error Cannot find source file in cmake?

Tags: c++, cmake

I am trying to create a shared library using the files present in SOURCE. So I added as suggested by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934295/add-source-in-a-subdirectory-to-a-cmake-project).

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)
project(myproj)

set (SOURCE
    ${SOURCE}
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/io/IO1.cpp
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/io/IO2.cpp
)

add_library(myprojlib SHARED SOURCE)
```

I get error even though I have set the source :

> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:34 (add_library):   Cannot find source
>   file:
>
> ```
> SOURCE
> ```
>
> Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm
>   .hpp   .hxx .in .txx

Comment: `add_library(myprojlib SHARED SOURCE)` should be `add_library(myprojlib SHARED ${SOURCE})` it thinks you mean SOURCE is the filename of your source cdoe not a variable.

Comment: Yup! that solved the problem. Thank you :)

Comment: @mato remember to mark drescherjm's answer as correct :)

Comment: Yes, will do :)

Comment: Typos are closed as typos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`add_library(myprojlib SHARED SOURCE)` should be `add_library(myprojlib SHARED ${SOURCE})` `CMake` expects that you mean SOURCE is the filename of your source cdoe not a `CMake` variable. The ${} syntax makes it clear that SOURCE is a CMake variable.