# how to write CMakeLists.txt to add header files and external libs which are in /include subdirectory and /library subdirectory

Tags: c++, cmake

I am following the basic tutorial by CMake https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.21/guide/tutorial/A%20Basic%20Starting%20Point.html

However, I want to run extra steps: moving the source codes files, output build and external lib into sub folders as below:

[image]

root/CMakeLists.txt

root/source/          => main.cpp and other cpp files

root/source/include/  => include header files

root/library          => include library files for future use. In addition, I want to include some linux library such as pthread as well.

root/build/           => include output built binary

My CMakeList.txt so far:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.10)
project (Car VERSION 1.0)

#set build options or set C++ standard
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

#set project binary folder:
SET(PROJECT_BINARY_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/)

#set project source folder:
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/source/include/
)

#add executable target name (if project is built as executable)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cxx modelX.cxx upgrade.cxx usage.cxx)

#configure header files to pass the version number to the source code (must add target_include_directories to the end of CMakeLists.txt)
configure_file(car.h modelX.h upgrade.h Usage.h)

#set target build
target_include_directories(Car Public "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}")
```

Thank you !

p.s: I found similar questions here: [Add Source in a subdirectory to a cmake project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934295/add-source-in-a-subdirectory-to-a-cmake-project).

However, I still can't make use of both suggested answers and the one below it yet.

Comment: BTW, the usage `configure_file(car.h modelX.h upgrade.h Usage.h)` is wrong: the command [configure_file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.21/command/configure_file.html) accepts only a single input and a single output file.