# How to combine the functionality of source_group and target_sources in CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake

thanks to [this answer regarding source_group](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56496104/5824979) and [this answer regarding target_sources](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54285898/5824979). I really cleaned up a lot of the way I managed my code base with calling nested CMakeLists.txt files rather than `<subdirectory_name>.cmake` files. However, I wanted to know if there was a way to further filter `source_group(TREE ...)`?

As I have it set up right now I have the `source_group` filters at the root, or parent, CMakeLists.txt file and I have a giant mess of the following:

```
source_group("subdirectory_name/Header Files" FILES ${libName_subdirectory_name_HEADER_FILES})
source_group("subdirectory_name/Source Files" FILES ${libName_subdirectory_name_SOURCES})
```

And I have at least 21 subdirectories in this current library. And some of these subdirectories have subdirectories within them. I would like to keep the same pattern if I can since the rest of my project is already set up like this. So it was really nice to know that I could do:

```
get_target_property(libName_SOURCES libName SOURCES)
source_group(TREE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIRECTORY} FILES ${libName_SOURCES})
```

And it neatly organizes the subdirectories with their sources and header files. However, I would like to further filter that so the headers and files are not combined in the same folder.

Right now, the Visual Studio Project looks like this:

```
libName
-- subDir1
   -- header.hpp
   -- source.cpp
-- subDir2
   -- header.hpp
   -- header.cpp
```

What I want to achieve:

```
libName
-- subDir1
   -- Header Files
      -- header.hpp
   -- Source Files
      -- source.cpp
-- subDir2
   -- Header Files
      -- header.hpp
   -- Source Files
      -- source.cpp
```

Is there a way to accomplish this with `source_group(TREE`? or do I have to create a custom `source_group` in a for loop that will parse everything in a way that I would like it?

Here is a small example of what my project currently looks like:

```
cmake_minimum_reqiured(VERSION 3.18)

project(myLib)

set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY USE_FOLDERS ON)

add_library(myLib SHARED)

add_subdirectory(subDir1)
add_subdirectory(subDir2)

get_target_property(myLib_SOURCES myLib SOURCES)

source_group(TREE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} FILES ${myLib_SOURCES})

set_target_properties(myLib PROPERTIES FOLDER "Lib")
```

subDir1/2 CMakeLists.txt file:

```
target_sources(myLib PUBLIC header.hpp source.cpp)
```

Thanks!